# How execute user defined function sql which is returning a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am working with SQL server 2012.

i have created a function in sql like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_IsCompanyExistInUserLocation](@CompanyId int)

RETURNS @Result table
(
UserId int null
)
AS
BEGIN
    insert into @Result(UserId) select UL.UserId FROM [RRT_Reporting].[dbo].[UserLocation] as UL where UL.CompanyId=@CompanyId and UL.LocationType='COMPANY'


    RETURN 
END
```

i am not sure its right way or not.

now i am trying to execute this function like :

```
DECLARE @ret as table (UserId int null) 

EXEC @ret = [dbo].[Fn_IsCompanyExistInUserLocation] @CompanyId= 10; 

select UserId from @ret
```

and i am getting error:

```
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@ret".
```

Comment: You don't need to tell us e.g. that you'll mark the answer that works as accepted. That's how SO *works*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @ret table (UserId int null) 
insert into @ret select * from [dbo].[Fn_IsCompanyExistInUserLocation](10)
select UserID from @ret
```

Comment: it gives an error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Fn_IsCompanyExistInUserLocation](10)
```

Comment: So are you using `@ret` variable at all now?

Comment: dude i tried to test Fn_IsCompanyExistInUserLocation function.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/enus/library/aa214485(v=sql.80).aspx is really helpfull

Comment: Yes. Always look at the official docs first when starting out!